# Script not running on Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, cross-browser

My script is working fine on everything except internet explorer. I'm not sure if it because I am using unsupported syntax or functions or what but if someone could take a look and see if anything stands out to them it would be really appreciated.

The basic implementation of the script is to create a simple shopping cart list when users click on a button. The total increments to include the added item and the item name, quantity and price is listed.

I have other scripts that work on my page so I know it is possible to implement onclick for example but I am unsure how to proceed here.

```
    <div class="product-div" id="big-blue-barrel-div">
            <h3>Big Blue barrel- $199</h3>
            <div class="img-div">
              <img src="images/barrel-pic.png" alt="picture of barrel" class="product-img">
            </div>
            <span>Quantity: </span>
            <input class="qty bigBlueBarrelQty" type="number" name="qty" value="1" min="1" id="bigBlueBarrelQty">
            <button type="button" onclick="addData(this.id, 'bigBlueBarrelQty')" name="button" id="bigBlueBarrel">Add to Cart</button>
          </div>
```

```
    var values = {
    bigBlueBarrel: {
      name: "Big Blue Barrel",
      price: 199
    },
    bigBlueBox: {
      name: "Big Blue Box",
      price: 399
    },
    babyBlueBarrel: {
      name: "Baby Blue Barrel",
      price: 99
    }
  }


  var total = 0;
  var rowCount = 1;

  function addData(clicked_id, quantity) {
    var price = values[clicked_id].price;
    var qty = document.getElementById(quantity).value;
    var lineTotal = price * qty;

    total += lineTotal;
    document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;

    addRow(clicked_id, qty, lineTotal);

    if (qty == 1) {
      alert(`${qty} ${values[clicked_id].name} has been added to your cart!

      Scroll down to view your cart.`)
    } else if (qty > 1) {
      alert(`${qty} ${values[clicked_id].name}s have been added to your cart!

      Scroll down to view your cart`);
    }
  }

  function addRow(clicked_id, qty, lineTotal) {
    var rows = "";
    if (rowCount % 2 != 0 ) {
      rows += `<tr class="odd"><td>${values[clicked_id].name}</td><td class="row-qty">${qty}</td><td>$${lineTotal}</td><td class="delete"><button onclick="deleteRow(this)" class="delete-btn">delete</button></td></tr>`;
      $(rows).appendTo("#cart tbody");
      rowCount++;
    } else {
      rows += `<tr class="even"><td>${values[clicked_id].name}</td><td class="row-qty">${qty}</td><td>$${lineTotal}</td><td class="delete"><button onclick="deleteRow(this)" class="delete-btn">delete</button></td></tr>`;
      $(rows).appendTo("#cart tbody");
      rowCount++;
    }
  }

  function deleteRow(r) {
    var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById("cart").deleteRow(i);
  }
```

Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of features in ES6 will not work in IE.

[`Template literals`](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) for example:
    `${qty} ${values[clicked_id].name}`

In this case you need to rewrite your `template literals` into normal strings using quotes:

```
     alert(qty + " " + values[clicked_id].name + " has been added to your cart!"+
      "\n\n" +
      "Scroll down to view your cart.");
```

This website: 
https://caniuse.com/#search=template%20literals

and MDN are valuable resources when I comes to compatibility.

---

Rewrite:
Tested on IE and it works!

```js
var values = {
  bigBlueBarrel: {
    name: "Big Blue Barrel",
    price: 199
  },
  bigBlueBox: {
    name: "Big Blue Box",
    price: 399
  },
  babyBlueBarrel: {
    name: "Baby Blue Barrel",
    price: 99
  }
}
var total = 0;
var rowCount = 1;

function addData(clicked_id, quantity) {
  var price = values[clicked_id].price;
  var qty = document.getElementById(quantity).value;
  var lineTotal = price * qty;

  total += lineTotal;
  document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;

  addRow(clicked_id, qty, lineTotal);

  if (qty == 1) {
    /*alert(`${qty} ${values[clicked_id].name} has been added to your cart!
    
      Scroll down to view your cart.`)*/
    alert(qty + " " + values[clicked_id].name + " has been added to your cart!" +
      "\n\n" +
      "Scroll down to view your cart.");
  } else if (qty > 1) {
    /*alert(`${qty} ${values[clicked_id].name}s have been added to your cart!

      Scroll down to view your cart`);*/
    alert(qty + " " + values[clicked_id].name + "s has been added to your cart!" +
      "\n\n" +
      "Scroll down to view your cart.");
  }
}

function addRow(clicked_id, qty, lineTotal) {
  var rows = "";
  //optimizing this:
  /*rows += `<tr class="odd"><td>${values[clicked_id].name}</td><td class="row-qty">${qty}</td><td>$${lineTotal}</td><td class="delete"><button onclick="deleteRow(this)" class="delete-btn">delete</button></td></tr>`;*/

  rows += '<tr class="' + (rowCount % 2 ? 'even' : 'odd') + '"><td>' + values[clicked_id].name + '</td><td class="row-qty">' + qty + '</td><td>' + lineTotal + '</td><td class="delete"><button onclick="deleteRow(this)" class="delete-btn">delete</button></td></tr>';
  $(rows).appendTo("#cart tbody");
  rowCount++;
}

function deleteRow(r) {
  var i = r.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
  document.getElementById("cart").deleteRow(i);
}
```

```css
table#cart {
  margin: 40px;
  border: 1px solid #e3e3e3;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table#cart td {
  padding: 10px;
  border-right: 1px dashed #f2f2f2;
}

table#cart td > button{
  padding: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #f2f2f2;
  background-color: #ff4444;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product-div" id="big-blue-barrel-div">
  <h3>Big Blue barrel- $199</h3>
  <div class="img-div">
    <img src="images/barrel-pic.png" alt="picture of barrel" class="product-img">
  </div>
  <span>Quantity: </span>
  <input class="qty bigBlueBarrelQty" type="number" name="qty" value="1" min="1" id="bigBlueBarrelQty">
  <button type="button" onclick="addData(this.id, 'bigBlueBarrelQty')" name="button" id="bigBlueBarrel">Add to Cart</button>
</div>

<!-- added for testing -->

<table id="cart">
  <tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
Total: <span id="total"></span>
```